# Calling methods upon DOM elements via JSInterop

Tags: dom, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

How can I call a Javascript method of a (DOM) `Element` given a `ElementReference` (Blazor) parameter in a jsinterop (`InvokeVoidAsync`) call?

I guess I could assign an id attribute to that element and then pass `document.getElementById("soandso").FunctionIWantToCall` in my InvokeVoidAsync call, but that removes some of the usefulness of Blazor...

Comment: I haven't made any code, as I don't know where to start. I'm aware I can pass an ElementReference through JSInterop, but I'd have to write my own Javascript to receive it and call the relevant DOM method(s) upon it, which also removes some of the usefulness of Blazor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nuget**: [SpawnDev.BlazorJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpawnDev.BlazorJS) - 14,000+ downloads

**GitHub**: [SpawnDev.BlazorJS](https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.BlazorJS) - examples and documentation.

SpawnDev.BlazorJS allows full **Blazor WebAssembly** and **Javascript** interop without writing Javascript. The library has 280+ Javascript objects wrapped in C# classes for interacting directly with the DOM, WebRTC, Encryption, WebGL, etc. And instead of writing Javascript to make a Javascript library work in Blazor, you can create C# wrappers around the Javascript library objects. The number of features is too long to list here. I am always ready to help with any issues that you may come across (see [Issues](https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.BlazorJS/issues)... 19 total, 0 open atm.)

I am the author of SpawnDev.BlazorJS.

C# example to access the DOM window:

```cs
[Inject]
BlazorJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

void AttachEventHandlersExample()
{
    using var window = JS.Get<Window>("window");
    // access properties
    window.LocalStorage.SetItem("myvar", "myvalue");
    // If this is the first time Window_OnStorage has been attached to an event a .Net reference is automatically created and held for future use and removal
    window.OnStorage += Window_OnStorage;
    // the window JSObject reference can safely be disposed as the .Net reference is attached to Window_OnStorage internally
}
void DetachEventHandlersExample()
{
    using var window = JS.Get<Window>("window");
    // If this is the last reference of Window_OnStorage being removed then the .Net reference will automatically be disposed.
    // IMPORTANT - detaching is important for preventing resource leaks. .Net references are only released when the reference count reaches zero (same number of -= as += used)
    window.OnStorage -= Window_OnStorage;
}

void Window_OnStorage(StorageEvent storageEvent)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"StorageEvent: {storageEvent.Key} has changed");
}
```

Using HTML elements via an ElementReference:

```cs
var video = new HTMLVideoElement(elementReference);
video.Src = "https://www.somesite.com/avideo.mp4";
await video.Play();
```

Comment: In a nutshell, I'd need explicit Javascript to make the sort of method calls or property changes I'd want?

Comment: The C# code does end up looking like explicit (aka strongly typed) Javascript. I try to make all of the interfaces as close to the Javascript spec as possible.  I rely on the awesome [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) a lot.

Comment: Well that's handy. If I need to start doing heavy lifting with DOM manipulation, I might use that. Meanwhile, I suppose I have no way around explicit javascript of my own, at least?

Comment: @hamstar it really depends on what DOM manipulation you plan on doing - hence my earlier question. Be very careful about doing DOM manipulation outside of Blazor - you generally only need JSInterop to call client-side functions rather than to apply structural changes to the DOM.

Comment: To clarify - any DOM state that is being controlled by Blazor should be left to Blazor to manage, otherwise your DOM manipulation will be done the next time Blazor renders the component.

Comment: @KurtHamilton that's an important note, but since this is all being done in Blazor WASM (AKA client-side), and since the DOM manipulations are client-sensitive (screen size, mouse position, etc), I have no choice but to find a way to work around the component rendering... which will probably be my next problem.

Comment: @hamstar then it sounds like Blazor isn't suitable for this project...